# How to execute 64bit application on 32bit ubuntu system?

Tags: lubuntu, 64-bit, software-installation

I have downloaded and installed Lubuntu latetest 14.10 32bit and now, after downloading [z88 aurora](http://www.z88.uni-bayreuth.de/z88aurora/download_e.htm) software (only 64bit is available for Linux), so I followed the installation guide, but the software doesn't execute and returns the following message in the terminal:

```
line 5: ./z88aurora: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

- Maybe someone can help me with this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you install 32-bit in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run 64bit application on 32bit Ubuntu.  You need a 64bit kernel to run 64bit apps.  see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/111975/can-i-run-64-bit-executables-on-a-32-bit-linux).

The only way is by using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), or [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player), providing that you have the required hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

A **32 bit** system can only run 32 bit programs.
A **64 bit** system can run 32 bit and 64 bit programs.

Read also the different between [32 bit and 64 bit](http://pc.net/helpcenter/answers/difference_between_32-bit_and_64-bit).